# Amortizing a loan using a loop with Java swing components . 

Tags: java, swing, loops

Okay, I am still new to Java, and I am going on my ninth week of this stuff. I am going to post some source code from a school project - this is NOT the entire source - this chunk of code is my loop to amortize a loan. I am trying to amortize from a menu selection (menu prints to a text field) or from user input. The problem is, and I cannot figure out if it is math, or my loop, is that it is not amortizing the loan properly. I just want to know if anyone sees something obvious that I missed, and if so could you please point it out so I can get on the right track? Thanks in advance!

SOURCE:

```
private void amortizeButtonActionPerformed( java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt ) {
  // This module borrowed from Ryan Jones in George Griepp's PRG 420 class.

  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  int Monthly = 0;
  int monthcount = 0;
  String Output = "";

  int i = 0; // For first loop
  double loanamount = Double.parseDouble( tempTextField3.getText() );        //all loan amounts  are the same  
  double rate = Double.parseDouble( tempTextField1.getText() );     //Array for the rate
  double time = Double.parseDouble( tempTextField2.getText() );         //Array for the time
  double totalnumpayments = 0;         //Set for 
  double monthlypayment = 0; //Set for math calculation in first loop
  double interestPayment = 0;            //Set for math calculation in first loop
  double totaltime = 0; //Set for second loop to know how long to loop
  double loan = 0; //Set for second loop
  double interestPayment2 = 0; //Set for second loop
  double principlePayment = 0;  //Set for second loop


  for ( i = 0; i < time; i++ ) {//First loop This loops through the arrays and gives the first message listed below three times
    monthlypayment = ( loanamount * ( ( rate / 12 ) / ( 1 - Math.pow( ( 1 + ( rate / 12 ) ), -( time * 12 ) ) ) ) );
    interestPayment = loanamount * ( rate * 100 / 1200 );
    totaltime = ( time * 12 );


    jTextArea1.setText( "" );
    jTextArea1.setText( "This loan has an interest rate of " + ( rate * 100 ) + "%" + " and a starting loan amount of " + nf.format( loanamount ) );
    jTextArea1.setText( "Payment Number\t\t" + "Towards Principle\t\t" + "Towards Interest\t" + "Remaining on loan" );
    jTextArea1.setText( "" ); // Part of the first loop this will appear three times with the math listed above


    System.out.println( totaltime );
    Monthly++;

    Output += ( ( monthcount++ ) + "\t\t\t" + nf.format( principlePayment ) + "\t\t\t" + nf.format( interestPayment2 ) + "\t\t\t" + nf.format( loan - principlePayment ) + "\n" );


    loan = -principlePayment;// Changes the numbers as the loop goes
    interestPayment2 = loan * ( rate * 100 / 1200 );// Changes the numbers as the loop goes
    principlePayment = monthlypayment - interestPayment2;// Changes the numbers as the loop goes

  }
  jTextArea1.setText( Output );
}
```

Comment: Since you're learning, I thinks that's the appropriate time to learn using a debugger.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them :-)

Comment: btw, what _is_ the problem? (as: expected/intended vs. actual behaviour)

Comment: @kleopatra - Sorry, didn't realize how vague I was. The problem is that the loop is producing negative increments, but I think the answer below solves that; the second problem is, I think my math as it isn't amortizing correctly. That could be my code.

Comment: @jb nizet - which naming conventions are you referring to? I am still learning so any feedback is helpful...

Comment: I'm not the one who mentioned naming conventions, but I couldn't agree more with kleopatra. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367. You have variables starting with an uppercase letter, and variables which don't use camelCase but are all lowercase. ANother problem is the bad choice of names: interestPayment2, jTextArea1, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things, which might be an issue or not (I am not familiar with the maths behind [loans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortizing_loan)).

1. You calculated `totaltime` in your `for`-loop, without making use of the `i` variable. Hence it will always result in the same result, and can be calculated outside the loop
2. By calling `setText` on the `jTextArea1` inside the loop, where your last call is with the empty `String`, you might as well clear it before entering the `for`-loop, as in the end the `jTextArea1` will just be empty. Or just remove the code since after the `for` loop you set the text to `Output`
3. The `loan = -principlePayment` is a weird statement. So if the `principlePayment` is a positive number, `loan` will be a negative number, and `interestPayment2` as well
4. You would better use a `StringBuilder` to construct your `Output` variable

I think number 3 is the most important for your calculations.

Comment: should I remove the i variable and just perform the calculation - or will that even work?

Comment: As I said, I do not know how to calculate loans. I just pointed out weird stuff in your code, which should allow you to use a debugger and investigate whether the result you get is the one you expect. But removing the i from the loop will not work

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Robin your comments gotbme in the right area. It was a }out of place affecting my entire output.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Robin your comments got me in the right area. It was a }out of place affecting my entire output.